# Convert an array to a mutable set in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, set

How does one convert a Scala `Array` to a `mutable.Set`?

It's easy to convert to an `immutable.Set`:

```
Array(1, 2, 3).toSet
```

But I can't find an obvious way to convert to a `mutable.Set`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
scala> scala.collection.mutable.Set( Array(1,2) :_* )
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 1)
```

The weird `:_*` type ascription, forces factory method to see the array as a list of arguments.

Answer (score 20):

```
scala> val s=scala.collection.mutable.Set()++Array(1,2,3)
s: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 13):

Starting `Scala 2.10`, via factory builders applied with `.to(factory)`:

```
Array(1, 2, 3).to[collection.mutable.Set]
// collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

And starting `Scala 2.13`:

```
Array(1, 2, 3).to(collection.mutable.Set)
// collection.mutable.Set[Int] = HashSet(1, 2, 3)
```